# Split string from the end with str_split()?

Tags: php

`str_split('12345', 2)` gives me `12, 34, 5`
Is there a way I can split it from the end instead and get `1, 23, 45`?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function str_split_reverse($str, $num) {
  return array_reverse(
    array_map(
      'strrev',
      str_split(
        strrev($str),
        $num
      )
    )
  );
}
```

You basically reverse the string, split it, then reverse each part and the order of the whole array of parts.

Comment: `array_map` first argument is callback, not array

Comment: Error: _Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_map(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback or null, array must have exactly two members_

Comment: @Justinas fixed, I always mix them up.